# How to call internal functions inside the constructor class?

Tags: python, class, self

Hello i have this code

```
class Test(object):
    def start_conn(self):
        pass

    def __init__(self):
        self.conn = start_conn()
```

But this code make this error:

`NameError: global name 'start_conn' is not defined`

If i write `self.conn = self.start_conn()` the program works without error, my question is, is a must to call with self the methods of the class when i'm creating a new instance? or is a desgin error from my side?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, you need to specify the self in python explicitly. Is there a "class" around your two methods?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, it's a must. You have to refer to the container in which the methods are stored. Most of the time that means referring to `self`.

The way this works is as follows. When you define a (new-style) class

```
class FooClass(object):
    def my_method(self, arg):
        print self.my_method, arg
```

you create a `type` object that contains the method in its *unbound* state. You can then refer to that unbound method via the name of the class (i.e. via `FooClass.my_method`); but to use the method, you have to explicitly pass a `FooClass` object via the `self` parameter (as in `FooClass.my_method(fooclass_instance, arg)`).

Then, when you instantiate your class (`f = FooClass()`), the methods of `FooClass` are bound to the particular instance `f`. `self` in each of the methods then refers to that instance (`f`); this is automatic, so you no longer have to pass `f` into the method explicitly. But you could still do `FooClass.my_method(f, arg)`; that would be equivalent to `f.my_method(arg)`.

Note, however, that in *both* cases, `self` is the container through which the other methods of the class are passed to `my_method`, which doesn't have access to them through any other avenue.